# My loop only terminates when the button is pressed after the last frame has passed

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to run some pixels on a loop in main. When I press a button the pixels are supposed to stop, but this only works if I press the button right after the last pixel has run. How can I make it so that if I press the button anywhere the loop just stops?

Here is the code

```c
int main() {
    while(1) {
        update();
        frames();
    }
}

void update() {
    if (button_pressed) {
        buttonPresses = !buttonPresses;
    }

void frames() {
    if (buttonPresses == 1) {
        pixel1();
        pixel2();
        pixel3();
    }
}
```

I tried changing the method to use while loop instead of if, but still does not work.

Comment: `if (buttonPresses = 1) {` ... `=` should be `==`, right?

Comment: `buttonPresses =! buttonPresses` is kind of misleading as there's no `=!` operator, it would read better `buttonPresses = !buttonPresses`

Comment: yes sorry. That was a typo

Comment: The code only runs `update()` once in each loop. If you want to interrupt the processing at some finer resolution, it looks like you should call `update()` more often, AND check the flag before starting the next operation.

Comment: OT: Your source misses a `}` for `update()`. Please get used to a decent indentation style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stop at any pixels you should check it after every pixel drawn. Something like this should do the trick.

```
void frames() {
    if (buttonPresses == 1) 
        pixel1();
    if (buttonPresses == 1)
        pixel2();
    if (buttonPresses == 1)
        pixel3();
}
```

Comment: How does `buttonPressed` change between the different read accesses? As it is now, there is no difference to the original behavior.